# R count number of Team members based on Team name

Tags: r, calculated-columns

I have a df where each row represents an individual and each column a characteristic of these individuals. One of the columns is TeamName, which is the name of the Team that individual belongs to. Multiple individuals belong to a Team.

I'd like a function in R that creates a new column with the number of team members for each Team.

So, for example I have:

```
df
Name    Surname     TeamName
John     Smith      Champions
Mary     Osborne    Socceroos
Mark     Johnson    Champions
Rory     Bradon     Champions
Jane     Bryant     Socceroos
Bruce    Harper
```

I'd like to have

```
df1
Name    Surname     TeamName    TeamNo
John     Smith      Champions     3
Mary     Osborne    Socceroos     2
Mark     Johnson    Champions     3
Rory     Bradon     Champions     3  
Jane     Bryant     Socceroos     2
Bruce    Harper                   0
```

So as you can see the counting includes that individual too, and if someone (e.g. Bruce Harper) has no Team name, then he gets a 0.

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it easier to first create a data.frame with only TeamName and TeamNo with groupBy and if necessary join with df on TeamName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution based on using `data.table` which perhaps is too much for what you need, but here it goes:

```
library(data.table)
dt=data.table(df)
# First, let's convert the factors of TeamName, to characters
dt[,TeamName:=as.character(TeamName)]
# Now, let find all the team numbers
dt[,TeamNo:=.N, by='TeamName']
# Let's exclude the special cases
dt[is.na(TeamName),TeamNo:=NA]
dt[TeamName=="",TeamNo:=NA]
```

It is clearly not the best solution, but I hope this helps

Comment: I did this and it worked, with just one minor issue. All individuals that had NA under TeamName now have a huge value assigned to them (as it counted all NAs). How can I include the option of "assigning NA if TeamName=NA"?

Comment: Thanks for comment, I have adjusted my answer. Is this working better?

Comment: Yes, it works fine when I have NAs (it assigns another NA in TeamNo) but when TeamName is empty it still counts it as 1. How do I add this little last bit so that when TeamName is both NA and empty it assigns NA?

Comment: Hi, my last attempt :). I hope it is better now.

Comment: Mmm not working :( almost there...there just seems to be something weird. When I run the two last lines now I get all NAs, even when TeamName is non-empty. Is the syntax right? mmm so frustrating...almost there...

Comment: It works with me here, so I just made is step by step now. Final edit :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know the number of `unique` members in the first two columns based on the 'TeamName' column, one option is `n_distinct` from `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
 df %>%
     unite(Var, Name, Surname) %>% #paste the columns together
      group_by(TeamName) %>% #group by TeamName
      mutate(TeamNo= n_distinct(Var)) %>% #create the TeamNo column
      separate(Var, into=c('Name', 'Surname')) #split the 'Var' column
```

Or if it just the number of rows per 'TeamName', we can group by 'TeamName', get the number of rows per group with `n()`, create the 'TeamNo' column with `mutate` based on that `n()`, and if needed an `ifelse` condition can be used to give NA for 'TeamName' that are `''` or `NA`.

```
df %>%
   group_by(TeamName) %>%
   mutate(TeamNo = ifelse(is.na(TeamName)|TeamName=='', NA_integer_, n())) 
#   Name Surname  TeamName TeamNo
#1  John   Smith Champions      3
#2  Mary Osborne Socceroos      2
#3  Mark Johnson Champions      3
#4  Rory  Bradon Champions      3
#5  Jane  Bryant Socceroos      2
#6 Bruce  Harper                NA
```

Or you can use `ave` from `base R`.  Suppose if there are `''` and `NA`, I would first convert the `''` to `NA` and then use `ave` to get the `length` of 'TeamNo' grouped by that column.  It will give `NA` for `NA' values. For example.

```
  v1 <- c(df$TeamName, NA)# appending an NA with the example to show the case
  is.na(v1) <- v1=='' #convert the `'' to `NA`
  as.numeric(ave(v1, v1, FUN=length))
  #[1]  3  2  3  3  2 NA NA
```

Comment: Would this assign automatically an NA (or 0) if the individual has NA under TeamName?

Answer (score 1):

Using  `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT Name, Surname, TeamName, n
      FROM df 
      LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT TeamName, COUNT(Name) AS n 
      FROM df 
      WHERE NOT TeamName IS '' GROUP BY TeamName)
      USING (TeamName)")
```

Output:

```
   Name Surname  TeamName  n
1  John   Smith Champions  3
2  Mary Osborne Socceroos  2
3  Mark Johnson Champions  3
4  Rory  Bradon Champions  3
5  Jane  Bryant Socceroos  2
6 Bruce  Harper           NA
```